# Could someone please explain how recursion functionality is working on working tree data structure

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

While I am working in the below code, I didn't understand how recursion is working, because insertLevelOrder() function after completing root.left functionality cursor is coming outside, but how root.right functionality invoking again.
As per the logic after incrementing 'i' value, in the middle again 'i' is becoming zero.

It is so much of confusing, please help me some one to understand, Thanks in advance.
    // Java program to construct binary tree from
    // given array in level order fashion

```
public class ConstructTree {
    Node root;

    // Tree Node
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node left, right;
        Node(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }
    }

    // Function to insert nodes in level order
    public Node insertLevelOrder(int[] arr, Node root,
                                                int i)
    {
        // Base case for recursion
        if (i < arr.length) {
            Node temp = new Node(arr[i]);
            root = temp;

            // insert left child
            root.left = insertLevelOrder(arr, root.left,
                                             2 * i + 1);

            // insert right child
            root.right = insertLevelOrder(arr, root.right,
                                               2 * i + 2);
        }
        return root;
    }

    // Function to print tree nodes in InOrder fashion
    public void inOrder(Node root)
    {
        if (root != null) {
            inOrder(root.left);
            System.out.print(root.data + " ");
            inOrder(root.right);
        }
    }

    // Driver program to test above function
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ConstructTree t2 = new ConstructTree();
        int arr[] = { 6, 6};
        t2.root = t2.insertLevelOrder(arr, t2.root, 0);
        t2.inOrder(t2.root);
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to understand code is to pretend you're the computer. Write the variables down on a piece of paper, then execute the code line by line, updating the variables as you go. Remember that when you call the function recursively, you get a new set of local variables, and when you return you go back to the previous ones.

Comment: To add on to what @Barmar said, it might be easier to reduce the test size so you don't have to follow the recursion down so many levels. Work with an array of 1 element first, then 3, then the full set. That way its easier to figure out the base case, and see how the recursive case plays out.

Comment: Thank you, surely I will try both the suggestions. appreciating your help Barmar and Dillon Davis.

Comment: To address a comment to someone  use @ before his/ hers user name like:  @c0der